# Unable to validate client certificate with Akka HTTP server (Play Framework)

Tags: authentication, https, playframework, certificate, akka

I am trying to set up an HTTPS server with client certificate authentication using the Play Framework (2.7). But the client authentication always fails with `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

The client certificate is signed by a custom certificate authority that uses a self-signed certificate. In my setup, this custom CA is the only CA that the server should trust.

In `application.conf` I added the following configuration to set up the HTTPS server and to replace the default trust store with the custom CA certificate.

```
play {
  server {
    https {
      keyStore {
        path = "/path/to/store",
        password = "password",
        type = "PKCS12"
      }
      needClientAuth = true
    }
  }
}

ssl-config {
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      { type = "PEM", path = "path/to/ca/certificate" }
    ]
  }
}
```

With debug enabled, when the application is initializing, I see the custom CA certificate is loaded :

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=ca@mydomain.com, CN=CustAuth, O=MyOrg, L=City, ST=12345, C=FR
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=ca@mydomain.com, CN=CustAuth, O=MyOrg, L=City, ST=12345, C=FR
  Valid from Wed Jul 06 15:38:40 CEST 2005 until Tue Jul 01 15:38:40 CEST 2025
```

However, I also see the following lines a little further in the logs :

```
trustStore is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
```

I did not expect nor want the server to use the default JRE trust store. How can I completely disable it ?

Anyway, that should not stop the server to authenticate correctly the client - unless the trust store gets completely overridden (I hope that is not the case but I haven't proven it so far).

When the client connects, I see in the logs that its certificate is correctly read :

```
chain [0] = [
Subject: EMAILADDRESS=devnull@mydomain.com, CN=My User, OU="User#41183", O=MyOrg, C=FR
Validity: [From: Thu Jan 11 10:17:12 CET 2018, To: Tue Jan 10 10:17:12 CET 2023]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=ca@mydomain.com, CN=CustAuth, O=MyOrg, L=City, ST=12345, C=FR
]
chain [1] = [
Subject: EMAILADDRESS=ca@mydomain.com, CN=CustAuth, O=MyOrg, L=City, ST=12345, C=FR
Validity: [From: Wed Jul 06 15:38:40 CEST 2005, To: Tue Jul 01 15:38:40 CEST 2025]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=ca@mydomain.com, CN=CustAuth, O=MyOrg, L=City, ST=12345, C=FR
]
```

The client issuer matches the previously loaded custom CA certificate. However, the following error is thrown :

```
application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2, fatal error: 46: General SSLEngine problem
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

What do I miss or what am I doing wrong ?

Edit : I noticed that if I import the custom CA certificate into the default trust store, the authentication is working.

Edit 2 : seems to be linked to the default implementation of the SSL engine provider :

```
2019-04-08 13:21:46 +0200 [DEBUG] from play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 - Using default trust store for client side CA verification
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom SSL engine provider must be set, see [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/SettingsNetty) since `DefaultSSLEngineProvider` supports only `play.server.https.trustStore.noCaVerification = (true|false)` and fallback to default JVM trust store.

Don't be confused with some log messages and better debug the app. Your CA is loaded but to other SSL context than you need.

I had slightly different problem and ended up with overriding JVM cacerts because Play config does not provide me configuration I need.